# echo php output in html file

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a php code that gives me the following output: (its an array)

```
<img src="images/image0.jpg" />
<img src="images/image1.jpg" />
<img src="images/image2.jpg" />
<img src="images/image3.jpg" />
<img src="images/image4.jpg" />
<img src="images/image5.jpg" />
<img src="images/image6.jpg" />
<img src="images/image7.jpg" />
<img src="images/image8.jpg" />
```

i want to print or echo or copy or invoke that exact output in my html file.
what should i do?

here is my code php code for reference:

```
<?php
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
    header('content-type: application/x-javascript');

    function returnimages($dirname="./images") {
         $pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";     //  http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/
         $files = array();
         if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
                    $files[] = $file;
                } 
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
        //sort($files);         // http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
        natcasesort($files);    // case insensitive "natural order" algorithm :: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

        return($files);
    }

    $images = returnimages(); //will get the array containing the images
    foreach($images as $img)
    {
      echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />' . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: im confused. you want to put this in an html file? put your html in the php file around the php code `<html> ..stuff.. <?php your_code ?> ..more stuff.. </html>`

Comment: Are you having trouble with the sorting part?

Comment: Can you log your $images please ?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it! i got it backward, i was putting php code in my html file! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$output = '<img src="images/image0.jpg" />
<img src="images/image1.jpg" />
<img src="images/image2.jpg" />
<img src="images/image3.jpg" />
<img src="images/image4.jpg" />
<img src="images/image5.jpg" />
<img src="images/image6.jpg" />
<img src="images/image7.jpg" />
<img src="images/image8.jpg" />';

$file = 'images.html';
file_put_contents($file, $output);

?>
```

Or if you want to change your existing script:

```
foreach($images as $img)
{
  echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />' . "\n";
  $output .= '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />' . "\n";
}

$file = 'images.html';
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already echoing it into the HTML webpage

```
foreach($images as $img)
{
  echo '<img src="images/' . $img . '" />' . "\n";
}
```

if you need to save it to a file, use

```
$file = 'images.html';
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

as Radio stated